# Get attributes from multiple unique id's

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

I really need some help with this! What I am trying to do is find all elements starting with the id (i.e youtubeHolder). I need to get the attributes for each of them and define a variable for each so I can use them later.

How is this actually done?

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#export').on('click', function () {
        var contentMap = {};
        $('[id^="appendText"],[id^="youtubeHolder"]').each(function () {
            contentMap[this.id] = $(this).html();
            var YouTubeSrc = $('iframe', this, '[id^="youtubeHolder"]').attr('src');
            var YouTubeClass = $(this, '[id^="youtubeHolder"]').attr('class');
            var YouTubeID = $(this, '[id^="youtubeHolder"]').attr('id');
            var textElement = $('iframe', this, '[id^="appendText"]').attr('src');
            var textContent = $(this, '[id^="appendText"]').attr('class');

        });
        for (id in contentMap) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "post.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    ExportYouTubeClass: YouTubeClass,
                    ExportYouTubeID: YouTubeID,
                    ExportYouTubeSrc: YouTubeSrc,    
                    ExportTextElement: textElement,
                    ExportTextContent: textContent
                },
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you handle the processing of the array on the server side, s o you're not trying to send so many HTTPD requests in a row..what if there was 100 elements? you could only handle 2 requests at a time maximum, and if each one took 1 second, that's 50 seconds. Instead, simply pass that array to the server in one ajax call after the array has been completed (in the each function). Then use something like, `$('ele').html('Loading...')` in the `beforeSend()`, and then in `success:`, do `$(ele).html('Success!')`

Comment: Please add your HTML markup for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't answering your question, but I would recommend changing your code to something like this.

1. Add a class (for example `class="youtubeHolder"` to all elements with `id="youtubeHolder_somethingsomething"`.
2. Instead of `$('[id^="appendText"],[id^="youtubeHolder"]').each(function(){`, use something like `$('.youtubeHolder').each(function(){`